# NSLog outputs to console when running on iphone simulator, but not when running on device

Tags: iphone

Has anyone heard of that before?  It's making me crazy.

It happens only in the main app I'm working on.  Other apps *do* show NSLog's in the console when running on the device.

I've tried re-installing the sdk, rebooting the computer, cleaning, deleting the build folder, rebooting the phone, a million things.  I know the nslog code gets run because the exact project shows them in the sim.  Also, even nslog's surrounding the code that loads the initial view in appdelegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching do not display when run on the device.

The *app* runs fine on the device, but I get no nslog output to the console.

If anyone can help it would be so greatly appreciated!
--Steve

Comment: Clarify: are you debugging on the phone, or just "click the icon and run"ning on the phone? Do breakpoints hit? I have never had issues with this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking in the Console application, or in the Xcode console available through the Xcode Organizer? The former is used by the simulator, the latter is used for devices.